# Google maps Api licensing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Hi,**

My question is regarding google maps API licensing. I have an online cab service in which we get 2 locations and calculate the distance. And we show the user the map and distance between this 2 locations. As per google google maps API licensing can be used for free with following:

> (a) Free Access (No Fees)
>
> (b) Public Access (No Firewall).
>
> (c) No Use of Content without a Google Map.
>
> (d) Use of the Google Geocoding API is subject to a query limit 2,500
>   geolocation requests per day.
>
> (User of Google Maps API for Business may perform up to 100,000
>   requests per day.)

As above mentioned we satisfy all the conditions for free licensing.
Do we fall under free licensing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you've answered your own question - "we satisfy all the conditions for free licensing", though with the information you have provided it's not possible to definitively give you an answer.

The best thing you can do is make sure that you can be reached by Google in case they identify a violation.  You can do this by always using API keys (sometimes they're optional) and making sure that you monitor the email account used to register the keys.